# Function pointers in CUDA __constant__ memory

Tags: cuda

I have found some strange runtime behaviour while experimenting with function pointers in CUDA.

**Goal**
My goal is to make my function pointers choose which function to apply to two objects according to an internal property of the latter.
In short, I want to emulate C++ templates with a CUDA kernel - without actually using template arguments or `switch` clauses, but function pointers and `class`/`struct` members instead.

**Approach**

- Define my custom objects `struct customObj` with one property (`int type`) that will emulate the arguments of a template.
- Define a bunch of dummy functions (`Sum()`, `Subtract()`, etc) to choose from.
- Keep the list of functions to apply (`functionsList`) and respective `type` members to look up (`first_types`, `second_types`) in  `__constant__` memory, such that function `functionsList[i](obj1,obj2)` is applied to objects with `obj1.type == first_types[i]` and `obj2.type == second_types[i]`.

**Working code**
The following code has been compiled for Linux x86_64 with CUDA 5.0, on a GPU with compute capability 3.0 (GeForce GTX 670), and works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

struct customObj
{
  int type;
  double d;
  // Constructors
  __device__ __host__ customObj() {}
  __device__ __host__ customObj(const int& _type, const double& _d) : type(_type), d(_d) {}
};

typedef void (*function_t)(customObj&, customObj&);
// Define a bunch of functions
__host__ __device__ void Sum(customObj& obj1, customObj& obj2) {printf("Sum chosen! d1 + d2 = %f\n", obj1.d + obj2.d);}
__host__ __device__ void Subtract(customObj& obj1, customObj& obj2) {printf("Subtract chosen! d1 - d2 = %f\n", obj1.d - obj2.d);}
__host__ __device__ void Multiply(customObj& obj1, customObj& obj2) {printf("Multiply chosen! d1 * d2 = %f\n", obj1.d * obj2.d);}

#define ARRAYLENGTH 3
__constant__ int first_type[ARRAYLENGTH] = {1, 2, 3};
__constant__ int second_type[ARRAYLENGTH] = {1, 1, 2};
__constant__ function_t functionsList[ARRAYLENGTH] = {Sum, Sum, Subtract};

// Kernel to loop through functions list
__global__ void choosefunction(customObj obj1, customObj obj2) {
   int i = 0;
   function_t f = NULL;
   do {
     if ((obj1.type == first_type[i]) && (obj2.type == second_type[i])) {
       f = functionsList[i];
       break;
    }
    i++;
  } while (i < ARRAYLENGTH);
  if (f == NULL) printf("No possible interaction!\n");
  else f(obj1,obj2);
}

int main() {
  customObj obj1(1, 5.2), obj2(1, 2.6);
  choosefunction<<<1,1>>>(obj1, obj2);
  gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
  gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize()); 

  return 0;
}
```

**The issue**
The problem that I have found is that, as soon as I replace the datatype of member `int type` and related variables and functions (`__constant__ int first_types[...]` and so on)... the code compiles but stops working!

- If I change the datatype from `int` to `char` or `int8_t`, the memory checker throws `error 4` on my call to `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`.
- If I change the datatype to `unsigned short int`, I get a hardware stack overflow.

So, is anybody having similar issues when working with `__constant__` memory? I really have no clue about what is going on. As far as I know, `char` and `int8_t` are built-in types of 1 byte length, while the size of `int` is 4 bytes, so maybe it is about data alignment, but I'm just guessing here. Besides, CUDA is supposed to support function pointers on the GPU since compute capability 2.0. Are there any special constraints for function pointers in `__constant__` memory that I'm missing?

Comment: I'm not able to repro the problem on linux with CUDA 6.  [Here](http://pastebin.com/jtCPbztu) is my example.  Perhaps you should modify your code with a unique typedef that shows exactly which elements you are switching from `int` to some other type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the problem (error 4, unspecified launch failure) on CUDA 5.0 on 64bit RHEL 5.5, but not on CUDA 6.0.

Please update/upgrade to CUDA 6.